# Why does maven build only when the Nexus Anonymous user is active?

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I am building my code using maven and we have our repositories on Nexus. The only way I manage to run a successfully mvn install from the command console is when I enable the Anonymous user from the Nexus settings.

In order to make sure I have all the needed rights I added in the settings.xml the admin user.

```
<settings>
 <servers>
   <server>
     <id>serverIDblabla</id>
     <username>NexusAdminUser</username>
     <password>NexusAdminPass</password>
   </server>
 </servers>
<profiles>
  <profile>
     <id>myIDblabla</id>
<repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>repositoryID</id>
     <url>https://.../repository/myrepository/</url>
     <releases>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
     </releases>
     <snapshots>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
     </snapshots>
```

...

I use:

- apache maven 3.2.1
- Nexus 3.0.0 -03

Any suggestions?

Comment: You made sure that the ids of repository and the username/password match? You also activated the profile? You probably need to publish the whole settings.xml here.

Comment: Furthermore, if you only want to build against the repository, you might be better of defining a user which has reading rights only.

Comment: @JF Meier Considering that the anonymous user is working, I assume that the server ID and the links are right. Profile is activated, password matches, user matches. I doubled checked now. Regarding the users right, sometimes I have to deploy in one of the repositories so reading will not be enough. I try some things today and if they don't work I'll post more.